# Detecting CPU throttling in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cpu, intel, throttling

I want to write a PowerShell script that checks if my Windows 10 machine entered CPU throttling state (1,17 GHz instead of 2,29 GHz when it happens).

Unfortunately `Win32_Processor` class always returns 2295 MHz for `CurrentClockSpeed` object even though host is working at 1170 MHz clock speed.

Same for `wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed`.

Any ideas how can I get REAL current CPU speed?

[image: Host in Throttling State - Image]

Comment: Through performance counters? Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor Information(*)\Processor Frequency" and Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor Information(*)\% of Maximum Frequency" maybe?

Comment: Nope :< but thanks anyway

"\\host45\processor performance(ppm_processor_0)\processor frequency:2295"
 "\\host45\processor performance(ppm_processor_39)\% of maximumfrequency :100"

Comment: Depending on your system, some BIOSes provide (WMI) interfaces that might reveal this information.

Comment: Isn't "wmic" command responsible for this on Windows 10? Already tried that.

Comment: @Frosty Could you try running this command for a while? `while($true){get-wmiobject win32_processor | select-object currentclock*,max* | format-table -AutoSize;sleep 3}` The `CurrentClockSpeed` held for me but eventually showed different speeds after a [few iterations](http://prntscr.com/gnzd88).

Comment: @Persistent13 Nope, still 2295.